# Using the latest (r13) version of Android SDK Manager on win7 64 bit fails to retrieve repository.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, 64-bit, java

So I've got a brand new PC with win7 64 bit on it.  I'm trying to get up and running with android SDK and eclipse.  I've done this before on other win7 32 bit machines and never had issues.  But now on this new machine, I have installed JDK 1.7.0 (64 bit), I have installed eclipse indigo 64 bit, and I've installed r13 of the sdk from here.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

But every time I try to launch the sdk manager (yes, I did get it installed with the "back" and "next" trick to make sure it found java) it fails to download the repository.xml file. The error I get 4 times is:

**Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Invalid argument: connect**

Note that I did shut off mcafee firewall so I don't think that's the issue.  I also tried the tricks mentioned many many places about trying with and without https://...  I have a direct connection, so I don't believe I need a proxy at all.  And I've verified that URL can load the xml into chrome.

So I'm totally out of ideas now!!!  Please help!

Comment: have you tryed to download tha sdk again ?

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded and installed the sdk several times, and I've tried putting in the (x86) program files path and the normal path (i.e. 64 bit).  I've tried both 32 and 64 bit JDK and JRE's.  I've tried setting up eclipse first and then going to the sdk manager.  I just constantly get this same "reason: Invalid argument: connect" failure I showed above.  Note that I'm using "Eclipse Classic" but I don't think that even matters.  There is just something wrong with my connection with the SDK Manager.exe I'm thinking.  But I don't what else to try.

Comment: Should I try an older version of the sdk or an older version of the JDK?  Do I need to install both JDK and JRE?  Is there some issue with path's in the android bat files and other files in the sdk?

Comment: Oh, I also tried right clicking on the sdk manager and running as "administrator" but that didn't change anything either...

Comment: UPDATE:  So, I just tried using version "Java SE 6 Update 27" JDK from here and bam!  It works perfectly!  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I finally figured it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12832441/559525

Answer (score 0):

I executed `C:\android-sdk-windows\toolandroid.bat` to get the `repository.XML`, which opened the Android SDK Manager and downloaded the list of things to install. Then I clicked "Accept All" for the agreements.

The first time I tried to install, it looked like it did, but didn't. (Each item said "null" as it attempted to install.) After I put the proxy settings into the SDK manager `(Tools > Options)`, each of the packages (68!) downloaded. (I copied the proxy info from `IE Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings`.)

HTC and MOTODEV request logins when you attempt to install their packages, but I haven't created an account, and so just skipped them.