# No packages or platforms in sdk manager

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

In sdk manager i can't see any packages to install or any platforms.

I have tried running the sdk as administrator and disabling the antivirus program and firewall. And i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it several times with no success.

I have version 18 installer_r18_windows.exe and the ADT is 18 too.

Thanks in advance
Regards
Tasneem

Comment: The current tools are R20, not R18. Try using the current edition.

Comment: i used R20 but its have a lot of problems and its not same as R18 .. when i create a new application project there is a lot of error in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your ADT first 
in eclipse choose help->check all updates
if it's still not working maybe you should check your SDK location in windows->preferences->android

Comment: are you sure your ADT is 18?
if still not working,maybe the best solution is reinstalling the eclipse,and btw what version of eclipse are you using right now?

Answer (score 6):

I believe I found the answer.  I'm on Windows 7, and was having this same trouble.  I did the following:

1. install the android sdk and latest Java 7 JDK
2. find the sdk batch file "android.bat" (for me it was at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools)
3. edit this file and go to the end where it runs the final java command with the variable %java_exe%
4. Add **-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true** right after the %java_exe%

For me the line looked like this at the end:

```
call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG% -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="%tools_dir%" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir% -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

I then see all the packages properly show up when I run "SDK Manager" from the windows start menu.  **NOTE!  When I run it I right click and choose "run as administrator" which I think is always a good idea so that it has permission to add files etc.**

I found this solution by finding this article:

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/java-net-SocketException-caught-when-connecting-to-the-target-host-Invalid-argument-connect-td5715972.html

Comment: YOU LEGEND! (This one has been plaguing me for a long time...)

Comment: Thanks!  Yea, it was REALLY driving me nuts too.  :-)

Comment: Oh god, I think I tried like 10 different solutions but nothing worked beside that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After trying some hard answers I found that it is more easier then I think:
Just open `SDK-manager` and click on `Tools`- `Options` and click on the `Enable preview tools` option. Then you will see all the packages in the `SDK-manager`.