# Issue with java.net.preferIPv4Stack

Tags: java

Hi I've been trying to fix an issue of my IDE and I read in another question that the solution was to pass `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` as an option but when I do i get an error msg

```
 C:/PROGRA~1/Java/jre7/bin\java.exe "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, (tranlation: not recognizes as internal or external command)
```

I've been having a hard time finding the documentation on Oracle's site.

if relevant I'm using jre7

Edit: post of the original question

[No packages or platforms in sdk manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639592/)

thank you

Comment: Are you using quotes to pass in -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack? If so, don't.

Comment: Can you please link the question you are talking about?

Comment: I've added it as an enviroment variable in _JAVA_OPTIONS